How can a Ger Toshav have an idol?
Leviticus 25:47:

וְכִ֣י תַשִּׂ֗יג יַ֣ד גֵּ֤ר וְתוֹשָׁב֙ עִמָּ֔ךְ וּמָ֥ךְ אָחִ֖יךָ עִמּ֑וֹ וְנִמְכַּ֗ר לְגֵ֤ר תּוֹשָׁב֙ עִמָּ֔ךְ א֥וֹ לְעֵ֖קֶר מִשְׁפַּ֥חַת גֵּֽר׃


If a resident alien among you has prospered, and your kin, being in straits, comes under that one’s authority and is given over to the resident alien among you, or to an offshoot of an alien’s family,

Rashi says that the end of the posuk refers to

to one who sells himself to the idol itself — to be its servant

but how can a Ger Toshav have an Idol?!

You're missing Rashi's comment there on משפחת גר, that it refers to the (still idolatrous) family of the ger toshav. So the verse is referring to three cases: being sold to a ger toshav, to idol worshipers, or to the idol itself.

@Meir: How can his "still idolatrous" family be allowed to settle in the Land?!

Who says they were allowed to? They may have remained in one of the Canaanite enclaves.

עי' רד"צ הופמן: לעקר – ...לדעת אונקלוס: ״לארמאי=לגוי; לפי זה ״עקר״ הוא איש ממשפחת גר, אבל הוא עצמו איננו גר אלא גוי
